# How to apply functions in Scala case class for transforming dataframes

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, dataframe, case-class

Quite new here. I'm trying to convert dataframe(with 2 columns a and b) to case class, use a function `mathAdd` on column A, and put the column in a new column C. I know the function `.withColumn` but really I don't know how to put these together. Below is my attempt with comments. Could anyone please help? Many thanks. *edited: One of the reasons why I want to use case class is because I'd like to save those functions for reuse.

```
  dfTest.createOrReplaceTempView("testTable") 

  case class testclass (a:Int,b:String){
     var result = 0    
     def mathAdd ={
        if (b=="apple"){
           result=a+1
        } else{
           result=a+2
   // but how to put 'var result' into a column? 
     }
   }  
 }

 var toTestClass = sqlContext.table("testTable").as[testclass] 
 toTestClass.mathAdd()
 //After this how can I convert this testclass back to dataframe?
```

Comment: If you have to convert the dataset back to dataframe why so complication when you already have a dataframe and you can achieve what you require with a dataframe easily?

Comment: Because in real life the functions will be more complicated, which might be too complicated for dataframe APIs..

Comment: Nope I guess not. Please see my answer below and if you still think it is complicated then we shall work on your case class method which I think would be complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean in real life that mathAdd function would not be like this, but with more logics. Also for my own learning purposes I'd like to know how to do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just invoke your instance method in `map` :

```
case class testclass(a: Int, b: String) {
    var result = 0

    def mathAdd: Int = {
      if (b == "apple") {
        result = a + 1
      } else {
        result = a + 2
      }
      return result
    }
  }

val tansformed = sqlContext.table("testTable").as[testclass].map(tc => tc.mathAdd)
```

This will get you a `Dataset[Int]`

But I would rather define `mathAdd` as a separate method, normally case classes are not thought to contain logic:

```
case class testclass(a: Int, b: String)

def mathAdd(tc: testclass): Int = {
  if (tc.b == "apple") {
    tc.a + 1
  } else {
    tc.a + 2
  }
}

val tansformed = sqlContext.table("testTable").as[testclass].map(tc => mathAdd(tc))
```

Comment: The second method got an error says 'reassignment to val', I guess you can't change the value of a column?

Comment: @user4046073 It works fine for me (see http://83.169.17.150:9001/notebooks/Test.snb)

Comment: @user4046073 maybe you are using the variable `result` somehere else in your code, try to use another name

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you intend to do with `case class` with simple `when` function and `withColumn` api

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._    
df.withColumn("newCol", when(col("b") === "apple", col("a")+1) otherwise(col("a")+2))
```

So I guess you don't need a `case class`.

Comment: apparently the logic is much more complicated than the example in the question, I would also suggest to pack that logic into a plain scala function rather than using spark functions